# Android: "Error parsing XML: must not undeclare prefix"

Tags: android, xml

I am very new to android development and was in the process of trying to create my first process when I came across the build error with which the question is titled.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app= ""
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/activity_main"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context="com.example.austinc.clicker.MainActivity">

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="0"
         android:id="@+id/textViewCount"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:textSize="24dp" />

     <Button
         android:text="Reset"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonClick"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ButtonClick"
         android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ButtonClick"
         android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
         android:id="@+id/buttonReset" />

     <Button
         android:text="Click"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
         android:id="@+id/ButtonClick"
         android:layout_below="@+id/textViewCount"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

From what I can infer by double clicking on the error, the problem has to do with the second line of code (the meaning of which I have no idea). Is this a quick fix, or have I made a mistake somewhere in editing some piece of code?

Comment: Not sure how you ended up with that, but you usually want `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` for that line. Or, with your current layout, you could just remove it, as you're not using that namespace anywhere.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you very much; I couldn't really find any questions relating specifically to this error. This helped to resolve the issue.

Comment: This looks like a new issue, see: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223363

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue, searched for 15 minutes and found the solution, i modified first three lines in content_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.user.demoapp.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
```